# Teaching the Concept of Infinity to Children.

Tags: infinity, education

I was recently out with the family and we left it up to the children where we ate lunch (11 and 9 years old). They couldn't agree and were going back and forth calling each other names. This ultimately lead to the age old tradition of one kid saying to the other "You're stupid times infinity". Afterwards, the 9 year old asked me what infinity was and I attempted to explain it to him in the way that I understood it as a kid through audio and visual feedback examples.

Audio feedback (simplified): the loop created by a microphone and amplifier when the microphone picks up the sound coming out of the amp.

The example I used for visual feedback was the loop created by two mirrors. This was the one that really resonated with the kid and seemed to help them understand a bit better that infinity was without a limit (or endless as the kid understood it).

What I'm wondering, is if these are viable real life examples of infinity. If so, are there any more that could be used?

I read through a few of the other questions on infinity here on MSE and they didn't quite talk about infinity in this sense. This also got me to think that perhaps this is intentional and that we cannot have a legit real life example of infinity.

Comment: I like The Phantom Tollbooth. A few pages on infinity.

Comment: As a kid, when I would look at the night sky, I used to think that if I could fly out far enough into space, I would eventually reach a black wall.  I had no concept of infinity.  Now, when I look at the night sky, I pretend that if I were to fly out, I would never reach any walls.  To me, that is infinity (regardless of whether or not it is an accurate real life example!).

Comment: By the way, when you line two mirrors up in such a way that it seems there is an infinite descending chain of mirrors in each one, technically, there are only finitely many.  This is because each of the mirrors in the descending chain is a result of the light bouncing back and forth between one mirror and the other.  Since the light only bounces back and forth finitely many times, there are only finitely many mirrors.  But you probably wouldn't want to explain those nuances to a kid.

Comment: @user46944 Something like that did occurred to me. I thought mirrors would be easier to explain than a video camera recording the monitor that is displaying what the video camera is recording (creating the visual loop).

Comment: @WillJagy That is where I got the idea of calling myself a Mathemagician (despite not being a magician). Just that to the average person it seems like I do magic with numbers.

Comment: Since they can simulate nonphysical geometries, video games might be a good touchpoint. A specific example (which is basically the same as The Phantom Tollbooth's) is from Super Mario 64: Unless you've made enough progress, a staircase near the end will just continue on endlessly without end, and you'll return to the start quickly upon turning around. (So I guess one could be a bit absurd and say: "Infinity is never being able to fight Bowser.")

Comment: Take them on a long drive. The phrase 'are we there yet' will be repeated an infinite number of times.

Comment: Perhaps better suited to http://matheducators.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Initially anyway, maybe you should avoid the noun "infinity" and first introduce the adjective "finite". It might take a very long time, but you would eventually come to the end. It doesn't last forever. Then "not finite" or "infinite." You never come to the end; there are always more. It lasts forever. It never ends. Then establish the equivalence of "an infinite number of" and "an infinity of."

Comment: Similar question at [Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/15212/77)

Comment: In real life, we are often sloppy with the use of "Infinity". ALmost always, we mean an extremely large number, or a number we "feel" to be large although it might actually be small. Statements like "There are infinite many primes" would better be described with "No list of primes can be complete, no matter how long it is". There are numbers (like the famous Graham-number) that are so large that its magnitude is indistinguishable from infinity. We cannot grasp its magnitude, although the number is finite.

Comment: It is weird that in the religion the concepts of the heaven and the hell are based on infinity. Not extremely long periods are meant, but periods that never ever end, something we are definitely unable to grasp. On the other hand, physicists insist on a finite universe (in space and in time) probably because of the inability to understand a never ending universe which never began to exist and never will end to exist and neither with a finite volume. In short, we can describe the meaning of infinity, but we cannot actually understand it.

Comment: Concerning the question : It is probably best to start with large numbers, then continue with even larger numbers, and when the child has a feeling for very large numbers, it makes sense to mention the concept of infinity. It is not a good idea to start with infinity.

Answer (score 5):

To tell someone what infinity ... Take a sheet of $A4$ paper and divide it into two halves. Now take one of the halves and divide it again. Repeat this step indefinitely. Here ask the question 'Will this process finish?'.

Comment: actually, the process will finish at some point.. There are only finite number of atoms in that sheet

Comment: @typetraitor: And that's quite aside from the fact that eventually the child will pick up a piece of paper and actually try to fold it a lot, and will soon find that after about seven folds it becomes more-or-less impossible (at the very least with human hands alone).

Comment: @typetraitor an atom doesn't have a half side !!!?

Answer (score 3):

I teach infinity by using the number line.  Tell the child that each point on the line represents a number, where the numbers are arranged such that the larger numbers are on the right.  Then tell them that *infinity* is the number (the point) that is the largest (the farthest to the right).  If they're smart, they'll see that no such number (or point) exists.  *Infinity* is a concept with no counterpart number (or point).

Comment: By the way, in the future, you might want to ask questions like this at [Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Of course, I'm limiting the discussion to real numbers only (and not, say, the extended real numbers).  By teaching infinity as the point farthest to the right on the number line, the child should see that questions such as "What is infinity plus one?" are meaningless, because "by definition," there is no number greater than (no point to the right of) infinity.

Comment: And what happens when they actually draw a line (or look at the line you've drawn) and see that it has an end? Your answer merely relocates the problem to that of helping the child to conceive of an indefinitely long line.

Answer (score 2):

Infinity and Me is a children's book that literally and figuratively illustrates the concept of infinity, in a way that is accessible to all ages.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5T6t.jpg)